# how to give selected option in html5?

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a problem with my code, when i clicked option and refresh browser will give back to default option

html

```
<select id="harga">
        <option value="renceng" isi="10" selected>Renceng</option>
        <option value="pack" isi="40">Pack</option>
        <option value="dus" isi="800">Dus</option>
    </select>
    <input id="hasil" type="text" name="harga" placeholder="isi" value="10" readonly>
```

js

```
$("#harga").on("change", function(){
        var nilai = $("#harga :selected").attr("isi");
        $("#hasil").val(nilai);
    });
```

Comment: That's what you would expect to happen. If you want to save any changes, you will need to store the change in either a database record or as part of the current session, then set the saved option as `selected` on loading the page. If all you do is modify the DOM in the browser, the server has no way of knowing that the change occurred and is thus unable to make that change persist.

Comment: There's no problem with your code. The selected value just doesn't persist when you refresh, per "design".